Terms and conditions for food?
Imagine you have purchased some food item for consumption and upon opening it you find a notice printed (faintly and hard-to-read) on the seal that by opening and consuming the product you agree to the company's terms and conditions.  It might look something like this:

and sure enough, it contains a link (https://www.vitalproteins.com/tc) to very typical terms and conditions, including a binding arbitration agreement.
Having never seen something like this before, you can't help but wonder: is printing a link to terms and service on a food item and stating that you agree to those terms by opening and consuming it, actually a valid way to create a contract between the company and the consumer?  If, for instance, a quality control issue caused a large number of people to get sick, who then started a class action lawsuit, could the company in question reject the lawsuit due to their terms and conditions and expect that to be taken seriously in a court of law?

FWIW, because  "opening and using" is required, and returns are encouraged if you don't agree to the terms, the company would rapidly curtail this practice if a grass roots movement arose whereby enough consumers would open and return these containers for a refund.  Just saying!

Query if the analysis is different for the first time you make a purchase of this product, unaware of the terms and conditions, than it is in later purchases, when you know what is hiding there and may even have clicked on the website link in the interim.

@ohwilleke, your comment seems like an incomplete sentence...  (if, then what?)  Am I misreading it?

@MichaelHall I am wondering out loud is the legal status of this contract would depend upon whether you knew from previous purchases what was under the lid. It is a complete sentence, albeit a somewhat old fashioned sentence construction.

OK, thanks.  That helps me decode the grammatic structure....  I would presume that lack of awareness on the first occasion would be a key element of any claim.  Because it would be kind of hard to make an excuse after that, eh?

That's clearly a shrinkwrap

@MichaelHall I wonder whether this writing would obligate the supermarket to refund your purchase. The supermarket couldn't put this half-opened package back on the shelves, so it would be a loss for them that they then have to claim back from the producer. They would probably do it the first few times because the unhappy customer is a much bigger financial risk than the one food container but if you try to return these boxes on purpose on a larger scale things may be different.

Well, according to Disney, arbitration can do anything. At this point, it would not surprise me to learn that I could protect myself from people bringing torts for injuries in my house by hanging a consent form for an arbitration agreement above the door in small print.

If my wife opens it but I use it, is either of us bound by the terms?

Not just either, both.
